# Regex match all lines that begin with optional whitespace and a single quote

Tags: regex

Given a file like this:

```
'declare a string variable
Dim s as string

For x = 1 to 10
 ' add Hello to string
 s=s+"Hello"
End for
```

I need a regex to strip out all the comments in the code:

Regex would return:

```
'declare a string variable
' add Hello to string
```

Note that there may be whitespace before the quote and after the quote.

If it makes a difference I am intending to run this through grep to get all comments from a bunch of *.vb files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

search for this

`^\s*'`

`^` means at the beginning of the line
`\s*` means to match as much space as possible (optionally no space)
`'` is the comment that you're looking for

and match any lines that match that regex, and you can splice out all of the comments

Comment: Ah duh. I didn't have the multiline option switched on in RegExr. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To match a `'` at the beginning `^` of a line, use:

```
^'
```